# Как в ListView повторно выводить массив из 3х элементов 5 раз?

Tags: java, android

Читаю книгу по Android. По этому приложению, создал ListFragment которая выводит массив состоящий из 3 объектов. В принципе приложение нормально работает. В списке выводятся названия трех машин. Теперь я хочу чтобы эти машины повторно выводились еще 5 раз к примеру. Организую второй цикл for, и в нее вкладываю первый цикл for, который выводит модели трех машин, но не помогает.

Вот часть кода который выводит модели трех машин:

```
String[] namesCar = new String[Data.cars.length];

for (int i = 0; i < namesCar.length; i++) {
    namesCar[i] = Data.cars[i].getNameCar();
}
```

Вот рабочий скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот моя часть кода, которая должна повторять вывод этих машин 5 раз, но код не работает:

```
String[] namesCar = new String[Data.cars.length];

    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < namesCar.length; i++) {
            namesCar[i] = Data.cars[i].getNameCar();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте свой код: в нём нигде не используется `k`, а `i` принимает значения от 0 до `Data.cars.length-1`. Весьма логично, что массив до сих пор содержит только 3 значения (а ведь больше он и не вместит, его длина по-прежнему равна `Data.cars.length`).

1. Увеличьте размер заполняемого массива (число 5 соответствует желаемому количеству повторяющихся элементов):

```
String[] namesCar = new String[Data.cars.length*5];
```

2. Используйте переменную `k` (теперь будут заполняться элементы массива с индексами от 0 при `i=0` и `k=0` до 14 при `k=4` и `i=2`):

```
for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Data.cars.length; i++) {
        namesCar[k*Data.cars.length+i] = Data.cars[i].getNameCar();
    }
}
```

Пример работы на js:

```js
//Ваш класс автомобиля
class Car {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    getNameCar() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

//Ваш класс данных
let Data = {
    //Массив экземпляров класса автомобилей
    cars: [new Car("Koyota"), new Car("Folks"), new Car("Nazda")]
}

//Выходной массив
let namesCar = [];

//Преобразования
for (let k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < Data.cars.length; i++) {
        namesCar[k*Data.cars.length+i] = Data.cars[i].getNameCar();
    }
}

//Вывод массива
console.log(namesCar);
```

Comment: Переменная k нужна же чтобы просто цикл повторял, нет? Т.е. если мое приложение выводит названия трех машин, они же должны еще 5 раз повторяться, разве нет? И после твоего кода, приложение ошибку выдает.

Comment: Во-первых, переменная `k` ограничивает число итераций в цикле, используй**те** `while`, если хоти**те**, чтобы цикл "просто повторялся". Во-вторых, как я уже написал, массиву необходимо сообщать, в какую позицию **вы** хоти**те** поместить значение. У **вас** эти позиции постоянно 0, 1, 2. Я заметил ошибку позже, но сейчас её быть не должно

Comment: Спасибо Большое! Помогли !